# issue in running the mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-8.0

Query: -

```
@Query(value="select sqla.questionBO from StudBO sqla where sqa.questionBO.id != null and sqa.lessionId = :lessionId and sqa.studentBO.id=:studentId ORDER BY sqa.attemptedOn DESC limit 1", nativeQuery=true)
    List<QuestionBO> getSQues(@Param("studentId") Long studentId,
            @Param("lessionId") Long lessionId);
```

I'm upgrading my MySQL from v5 to v8 earlier I was not using nativeQuery = true variable and it was working fine, but I think now I have to use native Query as I'm using the limit function.

If I don't use nativeQuery then I get "`antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: limit`"
error at tomcat startup.

But when I use nativeQuery I get the table not found error "`ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'latest.studquesattemptbo' doesn't exist`" when this method is called.

I checked my.ini file and there "lower_case_table_names=1" is already present as pointed in this link "https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/47334/enterprise-dashboard-error-sqlexceptionh.html"

Edit1:-
its BO.

```
 @Table(name = "student_question_attempt")
    public class StudQuesAttemptBO implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "ATTEMPTED_ON")
    private Timestamp attemptedOn;

    //@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    private StudentBO studentBO;

   // @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID")
    private QuestionBO questionBO;
    
    @Column(name = "SCORE")
    private Double score;
    
    @Column(name = "LESSION_ID")
    private Long lessionId;
```

Edit2:-

if i use table name instead of BO then getting:-

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'sqla.questionBO' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Are you sure the table studquesattemptbo (what a cruel name. no one can imagine what this table is good for) is existing in the database "latest"?

Comment: yes it exist in db

Comment: @Thallius i have edited my question if possible can you please provide any inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of changing the query to native query use "`Pageable firstRecord = PageRequest.of(0, 1);`" and pass this in the parameter of the method call